# AS3 flash.net.FileReferenceList.browse() accepts an array of FileFilter objects but seems Mac OS is using only the first element

Tags: actionscript-3, file-upload, filefilter

I have a file upload component written in ActionScript 3. The component is using the **FileReferenceList.browse()** to let the user select the files to upload. This method accepts an array of FileFilter objects to narrow down the selectable file types.

Until this time I passed only one FileFilter element in the array - if I passed any. This worked well for years without any problem. But recently I ran into a situation when **I thought I understand why this method takes an array** of FileFilters. Probably I was wrong...

I have a service which designed (and used) to present visual material mainly (images), but it can deal with non-visual files too like .xls, .doc, .zip, etc. This means in practice that my admin will upload almost only images (99%) to this service BUT sometimes (s)he will upload 1-2 .xls, .doc or .zip, etc.

So from this point I didn't want to really block files outside the (image) filter. Just tried to "show" my admin user that the preferred files are images here, but at the end of the day (s)he must be able to upload any file type.

So, I did this:

```
var fileReferenceList : FileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();
var imgFilefilter : FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png");
var allFilesFilter : FileFilter = new FileFilter("All files", "*");
fileReferenceList.browse([imgFileFilter, allFilesFilter]);
```

This worked well - on Windows. When the file browser window comes up my user sees the image files only. But (s)he can switch to "all files" view and upload other files too.

But now it turned out my Mac users are screwed this way... The file browser window doesn't offer the possibility to switch to "All files" view, so they can not upload non-image files :-) arghhhh!

I'm wondering what could be the best solution for the problem I tried to describe above? A trivial solution could be that for Mac users I skip the FileFilter stuff entirely. But it is not the way I would prefer... OR did I missed something? **Is it possible to somehow "convince" Mac file browser window to offer the possibility let my admin choose between the filters like Win file selector does?**

Comment: I confirm that only the first file filter you set will work on Mac OS. I don't think you can force the browser window to offer any other possibility. But one solution may be to do this filtering in your application and then create the FileFilter dynamically according to some user choice. For example, your users would first have to choose whether they want to upload an image or something else. Your application will then open a file browser with the according filter.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation! I had the same feeling about this.. :-(